# Android oreo crash signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR)

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-8.0-oreo

I have been seeing several such crashes only on Android 8 with no sensible stack trace.
How to identify the root cause? There seems to be no way to identify the library causing this failure.

```
backtrace:
  #00  pc 0000000000263fec  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art6mirror5Class24ResolvedMethodAccessTestILb1ELb1ELNS_10InvokeTypeE0EEEbNS_6ObjPtrIS1_EEPNS_9ArtMethodEjNS4_INS0_8DexCacheEEE+352)
  #01  pc 00000000002975fc  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL8DoInvokeILNS_10InvokeTypeE0ELb0ELb1EEEbPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+508)
  #02  pc 000000000028c578  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter17ExecuteSwitchImplILb1ELb0EEENS_6JValueEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameES2_b+36540)
  #03  pc 000000000025d450  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb+664)
  #04  pc 0000000000263a74  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter33ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridgeEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameEPNS_6JValueE+212)
  #05  pc 000000000027cd68  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb1EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+1520)
  #06  pc 0000000000295ca4  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL8DoInvokeILNS_10InvokeTypeE1ELb0ELb1EEEbPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+676)
  #07  pc 000000000028c988  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter17ExecuteSwitchImplILb1ELb0EEENS_6JValueEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameES2_b+37580)
  #08  pc 000000000025d450  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb+664)
  #09  pc 0000000000263a74  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter33ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridgeEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameEPNS_6JValueE+212)
  #10  pc 000000000027c5d8  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+640)
  #11  pc 00000000004f0bb8  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeStatic+468)
  #12  pc 00000000004f9914  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+14612)
  #13  pc 000000000025d374  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb+444)
  #14  pc 0000000000263a74  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter33ArtInterpreterToInterpreterBridgeEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemEPNS_11ShadowFrameEPNS_6JValueE+212)
  #15  pc 000000000027c5d8  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreter6DoCallILb0ELb0EEEbPNS_9ArtMethodEPNS_6ThreadERNS_11ShadowFrameEPKNS_11InstructionEtPNS_6JValueE+640)
  #16  pc 00000000004f27b8  /system/lib64/libart.so (MterpInvokeVirtualQuick+680)
  #17  pc 00000000004fd514  /system/lib64/libart.so (ExecuteMterpImpl+29972)
  #18  pc 000000000025d374  /system/lib64/libart.so (_ZN3art11interpreterL7ExecuteEPNS_6ThreadEPKNS_7DexFile8CodeItemERNS_11ShadowFrameENS_6JValueEb+444)
  #19  pc 00000000004e3514  /system/lib64/libart.so (artQuickToInterpreterBridge+1468)
  #20  pc 000000000051121c  /system/lib64/libart.so (art_quick_to_interpreter_bridge+92)
  #21  pc 000000000083cf74  /data/app/com.example.test-J16cmsw6mZ2mJRQy0VeYlQ==/oat/arm64/base.odex
```

Comment: Occasionally, Android apps crash through no fault of the app. Right now, I'm looking at a report with signal 6 caused by an SSL handshake during an HTTP download. Close the issue as "not repeatable".

Comment: That is a very unfortunate but maybe correct assessment for some apps. I'm looking at a similar SIGSEGV and it caused about 170 crashes to 11 users, so it looks pretty much like a blocker for them and it would really be good if there was a way to help them, even if it meant to remove a feature for Android 8.0 devices.